# How to simplify this equation of acceleration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does:

$$I\frac{a}{R}= -R(m_1g+m_1a)+R(m_2g-m_2a)$$

becomes:

$$a = \left(\frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2+\frac{I}{R^2}} \right)g$$

for context this is the equation for the acceleration of the atwood machine where I is the moment of inertia

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how does the first equation become the second

Comment: @VOZESTOICA See what you get when you solve the first equation for $a$.

Comment: I get a lot of R^2 terms divided by I

Comment: Ah, the Atwood machine, bane of every Physics 101 student. Are you just uncertain how to do the algebra to make this work out? I might recommend first distributing the terms on the RHS, rearrange so all of the $a$s are on one side, and *then* figuring out the division.

Comment: I am uncertain how to do the algebra to make this work out

Comment: OK, so you're having issues with the algebraic manipulation itself. Let's start with this: we manipulate the RHS to get $aR(m_2 - m_1) + gR(m_2-m_1)$. Do you see how I made that transition? After doing that, can you isolate $a$? (Side note: I'm not actually sure the second equation is correct, I think there's a minor sign error. Specifically, in the final form, the denominator should be $m_1 - m_2 + I/R^2$.)

Comment: the error was in the first equation m2g-m2a was the correct form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps. The idea is to put $a$ on the left, the rest on the right.

$a\left(\frac{I}{R}\right)=-Rm_1g-Rm_1a\:+$
$Rm_2g-Rm_2a\:$

$$a\left(\frac{I}{R}\right)=gR\left(m_2\:-m_1\right)-aR\left(m_1+m_2\right)$$

$$a\left(\frac{I}{R}+R\left(m_1+m_2\right)\right)=gR\left(m_2\:-m_1\right)$$

$$a=\frac{gR\left(m_2\:-m_1\right)}{\left(\frac{I}{R}+R\left(m_1+m_2\right)\right)}$$

Divide the R.H.S (top and bottom) by $R$, where R is not zero

$$a=g\left(\frac{\left(m_2\:-m_1\right)}{\left(\frac{I}{R^2}+\left(m_1+m_2\right)\right)}\right)$$

Comment: clever solution

Comment: did you divide by R in both sides?

Comment: No I divided by R the Right hand side both on top and bottom.

Comment: do you mean dive by r/r on top and bottom?

Comment: On the right fraction, dividing by R on the top gets rid of the $R$. On the bottom of the fraction: (I/R + R (m2-m1), dividing this by R gets you the final result.

Comment: I see 1/R/1/R = 1 however the R on the bottom on the sides of (m1+m2) does not cancel out

Comment: Ok, I will add a picture...Pls wait for few minutes...

Comment: R(m1+m2)/R I think that cancelation is violating the laws of math because the equation is left dividing by 0? or it is correct to cancel the R?

Comment: see: https://postimg.cc/dkG1kfGv

Comment: thank you sir..

Comment: It was tricky, I am glad its clear.